# Can't get updated value from service variable

Tags: angular, typescript, subject

I'm trying to apply a filter to search items based on a service variable which is updated with an input from that service. But I'm just getting the initial value from the service in my component

**Service HTML** (whatever I type in is assigned to the variable searchInput correctly):

```
<input [value]="searchInput" (keyup)="searchInputChange.next(searchFilterService.applyFilter($event.target.value))">
```

**Service TS** (it's called component since I already have a service with the same name atm):

```
export class SearchFilterComponent {

    searchInput: string = 'test';
    searchInputChange: Subject<string> = new Subject<string>();

    constructor(
        public searchFilterService: SharedSearchFilterService) {
        this.searchInputChange.subscribe((value) => {
            this.searchInput = value
        });
    }

    getSearchInput(): string {
        return this.searchInput;
    }
}
```

**Filter Service TS**:

```
@Injectable()
export class SharedSearchFilterService {
    
    applyFilter(filterValue: string) {

        if (filterValue) return filterValue;
        else return ''; // I need this to avoid getting 'undefined'
    }
}
```

**Component HTML** (here I'm getting the initial value which is 'test', then it never gets the new value from the service):

```
<ng-container *ngIf="searchFilterService.licenceFilter(item, service.getSearchInput())">
```

Link to an example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-buagfs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `AppService` in your sample is a component. You have to use `@Output` to notify value.

**app.service.ts**

```
@Component({
  selector: 'search-component',
  template: `
    <div fxLayout="row" fxLayoutAlign="space-between center">
      <input
        [(ngModel)]="searchInput"
        (keyup)="onKeyUp()"
      />
    </div>
  `
})
export class AppService implements OnInit {
  searchInput: string = 'test';
  @Output() inputValue = new EventEmitter<string>();

  constructor() {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.inputValue.emit(this.searchInput);
  }

  onKeyUp(): void {
    this.inputValue.emit(this.searchInput);
  }

  getSearchInput(): string {
    return this.searchInput;
  }
}
```

**app.component.html**

```
<hello name="{{ name }}"></hello>
<search-component (inputValue)="onInputValueEmitted($event)"></search-component>
<div *ngIf="searchInput == 'test'">This shouldn't be seen if value is not 'test'</div>
```

**app.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { AppService } from './app.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  name = 'Angular';
  searchInput = '';

  constructor(private service: AppService) {}

  onInputValueEmitted(value: string) {
    this.searchInput = value;
  }
}
```

[Stackblitz sample](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-9avpyn?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

Comment: Whole different approach, this one worked. Just curious: I was trying to avoid declaring a variable to read the component's input, is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

you need equal the variable `this.searchInput` to the value you pass to the function `getSearchInput`

```
//see that the function has an argument
getSearchInput(searchInput:string): string {
    this.searchInput=searchInput //<--first equal the variable
    return this.searchInput;
  }
```

BTW, Angular have yet a way to get your achieve: the FormControl and the [valueChanges](https://angular.io/api/forms/AbstractControl#valueChanges).

if you use a FormControl in your .html

```
<input [formControl]="control" />
```

In your .ts

```
//create a "getter" to access easy to this.control.value
get searchInput()
{
  return this.control.value
}
set searchInput(value)
{
   this.control.setValue(value)
}

control=new FormControl()
constructor() {
  this.control.valueChanges.subscribe(value => {
      console.log('Prueba de subject: ', value);
  });
}
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for this solution but I don't have anything to pass to the function since everything is processed at the service